# Join 4 tables and combine 1 table multiple row into one based on a key value

Tags: mysql, join

[image]

By joining first four tables .. how we can generate a fifth table in the image using mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.meetings_id,client_name,group_concat(concat(cc.contact_name)),summary from
meetings m 
   left Join client c on c.client_id = m.client_id  
   left join client_contact cc on cc.client_id= c.client_id
   left join meeting_attendees ma on cc.contact_id = ma.contact_id  
   group by m.meetings_id
   order by m.meetings_id
```